# POST 500 Error Bot Emulator Localhost for IIS hosted Bot

Tags: iis, emulation, botframework

I have used IIS to locally host my bot like so: https: //localhost/MyBot. Currently when I try to connect to my bot in the bot emulator I get a POST 500 error, and am unable to send messages. I am new to this and most documentation for publishing a bot to a local server is limited. I can however successfully open this link from my browser.

Am I experiencing this error because I don't have the https: //localhost/Bridget/api/messages directory/url? I tried creating Virtual Directories in IIS but that did not help solve my problem. Do I need tunneling software? Is there a simple tutorial for deploying a bot locally using IIS and connecting to it via the bot emulator?

Here is the error I see in the emulator:

[Bot Emulator Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMcpP.png)

Using ngrok tunneling software this is what I see:

[NGROK Bot Emulator Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dztx7.png)

Here is the code that processing incoming POST messages:

```
/// <summary>
/// POST: api/Messages
/// Receive a message from a user and reply to it
/// </summary>
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)
{
    if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
    {
        // Strip any @mentions
        Mention[] m = activity.GetMentions();
        for (int x = 0; x < m.Length; x++)
        {
            if (m[x].Mentioned.Id == activity.Recipient.Id)
            {
                if (m[x].Text != null)
                {
                    activity.Text = activity.Text.Replace(m[x].Text, "");
                }
            }
        }

        await stateClient.BotState.SetUserDataAsync(activity.ChannelId, activity.From.Id, userData);

        await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new Dialogs.RootDialog());
    }
    else if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Invoke)
    {
            // Some Code...
    }
    else
    {
        HandleSystemMessage(activity);
    }
    var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    return response;
}
```

Comment: You bot can be contacted as you get the `conversationUpdate` in the emulator so it's a good thing, now you have problems with treating / replying to an incoming message. Maybe you should try to reply with a basic echo first. And maybe log the exception on a file or somewhere, in order to be able to see what are these errors from the "server side"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue, it was because IIS was not allowing POST requests. All I did was go to Request filtering and added the verb POST:

[IIS POST Fix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/weGXN.png)

Answer (score 0):

> Am I experiencing this error because I don't have the https: //localhost/Bridget/api/messages directory/url?

Both your screenshots show you trying to connect to `/api/messages`, which you say you don't have, so naturally, you are going to get an error.

Please post the portion of your bot code to show where you are listening for the messages. For example, a NodeJS bot would have something like:

```
var server = restify.createServer();
server.listen(process.env.port || process.env.PORT || 3978, () => {
    console.log('%s listening to %s', server.name, server.url); 
});

var connector = new builder.ChatConnector({
    appId: process.env.MICROSOFT_APP_ID,
    appPassword: process.env.MICROSOFT_APP_PASSWORD
});
var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector);
server.post('/api/messages', connector.listen());
```

The last line shows the connecting listening for message at `/api/messages` in the current application (being run by NodeJS using the `restify` library). What does your's have?

Comment: I have been able to connect, but now I get a 405 Error in the bot emulator. Above shows the included code from Microsoft that handles messages. I am using the bot framework SDK. I published it to a file and then used IIS to create a localhost link. Now I'm trying to access it via the emulator that way. I don't think I should have to create a Virtual Directory called api/messages...

Comment: Have you modified your routing at all? What is the name of your controller file? By default, it should be MessagesController.cs, and if you haven't modified the route, your default route _will be_ `/api/messages`. Are you able to run this in Visual Studio without getting errors? For 405 errors in Web API, you might need to take a look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/troubleshooting-http-405-errors-after-publishing-web-api-applications).

Comment: When you publish the bot it generates a folder that doesn't include the MessagesController.cs file, but yes it is properly name. [Here is a pic of the issue I am now facing](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/8683055/27881854-d5a863da-618f-11e7-8114-dc903212daa2.PNG) For some reason I can connect to the bot but I can't sent POST requests?

Comment: The controller is compiled into the DLL, but my assumption is that you haven't changed the route, so you should still be pointing to `/api/messages` as your endpoint. A 500 error indicates an issue with the code execution. A 405 error has to deal with an improper or conflicting verb during a REST call. Are you able to debug your code locally? Start it up in Visual Studio, set a break point in the controller, and see if it hits?

Comment: I've tested my code and it works in VS. Now I am getting a 405 Error? It's saying that POST requests aren't supported at this time. I have added handers and edited my web.config file per instructions from the internet but nothing seems to get it to work? Shouldn't my config file and dlls take care of this? What is the proper way (step-by-step) to deploy a bot using IIS?

Comment: All of your photos show you pointing to `https://`. Do you have a valid certificate installed locally? Are you able to just connect to `http://`, which you should be able to for localhost debugging.

Comment: I do have a certificate installed, and I have tried both http:// and https:// I know at this point it has to do with IIS but I don't know where to begin to try to find out why the Application doesn't like verb requests